# Arrange Data (Finding average)

Tags: r

I have a dataset having monthly observations (from January to December) over a period of time like (2000 to 2018). Now, I am trying to take an average the value from March to July of each year.

**Reproducible Example:**

```r
zz <- "Year    Month  Value
       2000    1        25
       2000    2        28 
       2000    3        22
       2000    12       26
       2001     1       27
       2018    11       30
       2018    12       29"
df <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Can someone help me in this regard?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  year = rep(c(2000, 2001, 2002), each = 12),
  month = rep(1:12, times = 3),
  value = sample(1:1000, 3*12)
)

data.from.march.to.july <- data[data$month %in% 3:7, ]

data.averages <- data.from.march.to.july %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(value), .groups = "drop_last")
```